# Declaration in Typescript, should I prefer `| null`?

Tags: typescript

```
const val: MyClass
```

respective

```
const val: MyClass | null;
```

Which do I prefer? and why?

---

I can see a semantic meaning where first example says "`val` should always have a value (but due to technical reasons it might not - but then it is a bug)" while the latter says "`val` does not need to have a value".
Are there technical differences?

Comment: You can enable a compiler option which takes out `null` and `undefined` from all other values, so `val: MyClass` will *not* be `null`, while `val: MyClass | null` means it *might* be.

Comment: `const val: MyClass` should be a type error: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8C+AoLwD2AdhAC7QBuYIAXHEijAPQPQDk+RxL0AJgKahgATmGIBLQjAC2AVxLQARr2iiCosZVEAvXtwB0ACgCMhgKwmAlDixA Which means that `const val: MyClass | null = null` is the correct way to initialize as `null`.

Comment: Typescript can provide type safety only at compiler time. Once it's compiled to javascript, both definitions result in the same code. Of course you need to initialize a const with a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, with the default compiler settings there are no technical differences, [because](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#null-and-undefined):

> By default `null` and `undefined` are subtypes of all other types.

In that case, adding `| null` only serves as a reminder to the human reader of the code.

You can change (improve) this by enabling [`--strictNullChecks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html):

> In strict null checking mode, the `null` and `undefined` values are not in the domain of every type and are only assignable to themselves and `any` (the one exception being that `undefined` is also assignable to `void`).